# Timer restarts after clearInterval() instead of pause - What's wrong with my Timer? React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, timer, setinterval

I have a toggle button on which I want to start, stop a timer. There is also a reset button. But every time I stop, it restarts back. What am I doing wrong?

**timer.js**

```
import React, { useState, useImperativeHandle, forwardRef } from 'react'


const Timer = forwardRef((props, ref) => {

// We need ref in this, because we are dealing
// with JS setInterval to keep track of it and
// stop it when needed
let interval = null;

const [total, setTotal] = useState(3540);      

useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({

startTimerWrapper() {

        
        interval = setInterval(() => {
            setTotal(total => total + 1)
        },1000)

        console.log(interval);
    
    return () => clearInterval(this.interval)
},
closeTimerWRapper(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    console.log("cleared " + this.interval);
    setTotal(0);
}
}));



return (
    
    <>
        <h1 >
            <span>{("0" + Math.floor(total / 3600)).slice(-2)}:</span>
            <span>{("0" + Math.floor((total % 3600) / 60)).slice(-2)}:</span>
            <span>{("0" + ~~(total % 60)).slice(-2)}</span>
        </h1>
    </> 

)
})

export default Timer;
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {

const [started, setStarted] = React.useState(false);
const timerRef = useRef(null);

  const onToggle = () => {    
let id = null;
setStarted(!started); 

if(!started){
id = timerRef.current.startTimerWrapper();
console.log("1");}else{
timerRef.current.closeTimerWRapper();
console.log("0 " + id);}
}

return (
<div className="App" style={{ padding: 40 }} >        
    
  <Card className="main" style={style.main}>
    <CardContent>
      
      <Stack
        direction="row"
        justifyContent="center"            
        spacing={2}        
      >
        
  <Item>
          <StyledToggleButton                    
                value="false"
                selected={started}
                onChange={() => {
                       onToggle();          
                }}
              >
            <PlayCircleOutlineIcon sx={{display: started ? 'none' : 'block'}}/>
            <StopIcon sx={{display: started ? 'block' : 'none' }}/>
          </StyledToggleButton>
        </Item>             
      </Stack>
      <div justifycontent="center" display="flex"><Timer ref={timerRef} ></Timer></div>
      </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have provided a working example in sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-sun-cq0j3v?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

`interval` should be handled with useRef hook.

```
const interval = useRef();

// ...

startTimerWrapper() {
    interval.current = setInterval(() => {
        setTotal(total => total + 1)
    },1000)
    console.log(interval.current);
    return () => clearInterval(this.interval.current)
},
closeTimerWRapper(){
    clearInterval(interval.current);
    console.log("cleared " + this.interval.current);
    setTotal(0);
}
```